# How to connect azure website to blob in appsettings?

Tags: model-view-controller, blob, appsettings

I would like connect my mvc website to azure blob. I made a search and see that I should write in appsettiings my credentials and code with ConfigurarionManager. I do have a format exception:

No valid combination of account information found. Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.FormatException: No valid combination of account information found.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[FormatException: No valid combination of account information found.]
   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount.b__0(String err) +33
   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount.TryParse(String s, CloudStorageAccount& accountInformation, Action`1 error) +1554
   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount

I would appreciate to have the appsetting (key= value=) details and related code sentence with configurationmanager.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to post the code you are using, that makes it easier to help you. You can try this:

In web.config:

```
 <add name="StorageConnectionString" connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=XXXXXXXX;AccountKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

In your c# code use:

```
 readonly CloudStorageAccount _StorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StorageConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
```

Comment: why do you have providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" at the end of your connection string?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the asker might have copied the connection string from documentation as a start, or any thing that got the connection string deformed, in which case you get this exception.

Example:
In my case it was around DefaultEndpointsProtocol=[http | https], and the correct format is to remove the the brackets: DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https